# NPOI Vertical align and Center

Tags: c#, excel, interop, npoi

I am using the NPOI 2.0.6.0 and I am trying to position a cell VerticalAlign TOP and Center.

```
this._rowStyleLight.BorderRight = BorderStyle.Thin;
this._rowStyleLight.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
this._rowStyleLight.SetFillForegroundColor(this._rowColourLight);
this._rowStyleLight.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
```

The VerticalAlignment doesn't offer this.  When I set the `_rowStyleLight.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;` to be Center too then it seems as if NPOI cannot apply both.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
XSSFFont yourFont = (XSSFFont)workbook.CreateFont();
yourFont.FontHeightInPoints = (short)10;
yourFont.FontName = "Arial";

XSSFCellStyle yourStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
yourStyle.WrapText = true;
yourStyle.Alignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
yourStyle.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
yourStyle.BorderBottom = BorderStyle.Thin; 
yourStyle.SetFont(yourFont);

sheet.SetyourColumnStyle(col, yourStyle);
```